# MDX Top Count Sub total

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx

I am trying to create an MDX query to calculate the top selling stores for a territory, then subtotal the territory.

I have used the TOPCOUNT function with the GENERATE function to create a SET for the Top Locations, however I am having real trouble trying to sub total each territory.

My MDX is as follows:

```
WITH SET [TopLocationsPerTerritory] AS
    GENERATE( 
        Except ([Locations].[Territory].MEMBERS, [Locations].[Territory].[All]),

        TOPCOUNT(
             {[Locations].[Territory].CurrentMember} * Except ([Locations].[Location Hierarchy].[Location].MEMBERS,[Locations].[Location Hierarchy].[Location].[All]),
            5, 
            [Measures].[SLS ($)]
        )
    )
SELECT  {
            [Measures].[SLS YTD ($)],
            [Measures].[SbD BUD SLS YTD ($)],
            [Measures].[SbD BUD v ACT SLS YTD VAR %],
            [Measures].[SLS LFL YTD %],

            [Measures].[SLS GP YTD ($)],
            [Measures].[SbD BUD GP YTD ($)],
            [Measures].[SbD BUD v ACT GP YTD VAR %],
            [Measures].[SLS LFL GP YTD %],

            [Measures].[SLS ($)],
            [Measures].[SbD BUD GP ($)],
            [Measures].[SbD BUD v ACT SLS VAR %],
            [Measures].[SLS LFL %],

            [Measures].[SLS GP ($)],
            [Measures].[SbD BUD GP ($)],
            [Measures].[SbD BUD v ACT GP VAR %],
            [Measures].[SLS LFL GP %]

        } ON COLUMNS,
        (
            [TopLocationsPerTerritory]
        ) on ROWS
```

And the results are good.
[image]
However I have tried several ways and cannot get a sub total for each territory. I managed to get a aggregate of the whole dataset however that is not what I need.

Comment: It's going to very hard for people to help you. Perhaps you could create a simpler version of your dataset with sample data and desired results.

Comment: @Stephan - seems like all the required info is included

Comment: hi Will - did you find an answer to your question?

Comment: In my scenario there was an extra variable that was stopping it from working, so I split my results into a second dataset to overcome this issue. I've marked your response below as the correct answer as I believe it will resolve the issue for others. oh, and thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a `union` with the `All` member:

```
WITH 
  SET [TopLocationsPerTerritory] AS 
    Generate
    (
      Except
      (
        [Locations].[Territory].MEMBERS
       ,[Locations].[Territory].[All]
      )
     ,Union
      (
        TopCount
        (
            {[Locations].[Territory].CurrentMember}
          * 
            Except
            (
              [Locations].[Location Hierarchy].[Location].MEMBERS
             ,[Locations].[Location Hierarchy].[Location].[All]
            )
         ,5
         ,[Measures].[SLS ($)]
        )
       ,(
          [Locations].[Territory].CurrentMember
         ,[Locations].[Location Hierarchy].[Location].[All]
        )
      )
    )
...
...
...
```

Prototyping in `AdvWrks` the above seems to work fine:

```
WITH 
  SET [Top5StatesPerCountry] AS 
    Generate
    (
      [Country].[Country].MEMBERS
     ,Union
      (
        TopCount
        (
          [Country].CurrentMember * [State-Province].[State-Province].MEMBERS
         ,5
         ,[Measures].[Internet Order Count]
        )
       ,(
          [Country].CurrentMember
         ,[State-Province].[All]
        )
      )
    ) 
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[Internet Order Count]} ON COLUMNS
 ,{[Top5StatesPerCountry]} ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Here is a snippet of the result:

[image]

But the following is much simpler solution that does not bother with the `union` inside `generate`:

```
WITH 
  SET [Top5StatesPerCountry] AS 
    Generate
    (
      [Country].[Country].MEMBERS
     ,TopCount
      (
        (EXISTING 
          [State-Province].[State-Province].MEMBERS)
       ,5
       ,[Measures].[Internet Order Count]
      )
    ) 
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[Internet Order Count]} ON COLUMNS
 ,
    [Country].[Country].MEMBERS
  * 
    {
      [Top5StatesPerCountry]
     ,[State-Province].[All]
    } ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

---

**Edit**

You could amend the script immediately above to this:

```
WITH 
  SET [Top5StatesPerCountry] AS 
    Generate
    (
      [Country].[Country].MEMBERS
     ,TopCount
      (
        (EXISTING 
          [State-Province].[State-Province].MEMBERS)
       ,5
       ,[Measures].[Internet Order Count]
      )
    ) 
  MEMBER [State-Province].[State-Province].[AGGREGTOP5] AS 
    AGGREGATE(EXISTING [Top5StatesPerCountry])
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[Internet Order Count]} ON COLUMNS
 ,
    [Country].[Country].MEMBERS
  * 
    {
      [Top5StatesPerCountry]
     ,[State-Province].[All]
     ,[State-Province].[State-Province].[AGGREGTOP5]
    } ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Comment: Hey @whytheq, Thanks for your help, however when I do that it totals the whole territory value, not the value for the top 5. Sorry I believe my original post was misleading. Is there anyway of totalling the Top 5 only? (Your answer helped me with another query though)

Comment: @WillWainwright Hi Will - I'm sure that something is possible - but you need to encourage people via the up button (not a very subtle hint)

Comment: @WillWainwright hi will - I added some more logic to the last script - unfortunately I am not near SSAS for a couple of days so currently unable to test this addition - hopefully it helps to sum up the Top5 for you.